# Should we permanently delete the abusive edit history from the posts, which were [accidentally] approved for spam edits?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, editing, spam

For example, recently a couple of users have accidentally approved abusive edits of their posts:

- [Where does Vishwamitra's parallel creation of constellations of stars and galaxies exist?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28317)
- [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9196)

Should we hard-delete the edit history as they are publicly visible and serves the purpose of the spammer?

Also, [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196737) says only CMs have the privilege to delete such edits? Is this right?

Comment: This post will be longstanding and it's better to remove the "status-completed" from the main post and add it to the individual links. In future, if such spam approvals happen then we have to just add that link as another bullet. The "status-completed" of the main post gives a wrong notion that this question is done & dusted, now create a new one [duplicate]. However, if we want to keep these edits, then better to mention somewhere in bolds that, "flag such post" instead of meta. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @iammilind It is fine to have status completed tag. This was originally a support question asking to remove those edits but discussion was added later. We should not add spam edit into bullet points here. It is not useful. Those edits and suggestions should be avoided for public visibility. Instead of posting a new question again on meta, flagging the question for mod intervention is enough. Because we don't post a meta when we see rude/ spam post. We just flag. Same way should be done here. The mods are the one who should act not the users. This should not be ever running thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should be done. Not only Community managers, even [diamond moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191121/357396) can [redact a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/revision-redaction/info).

> [image]

A custom flag asking for redacting a revision and a link (it does the mod's job easier) will do that. It takes some time to complete though.

> [image]